# Forge Viewer Error

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

When I open the viewer I get these errors:

```
Failed to load https://ase.autodesk.com/adp/v1/analytics/upload: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://ontargetapp.local' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503.

2adp-web-analytics-sdk.min.js:4 OPTIONS https://ase.autodesk.com/adp/v1/analytics/upload 503 (Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity)
```

**How do I solve this?**

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to solve this - this is an OPTIONS HTTP request which does not need to be honored - It has no impact on the viewer - This is Autodesk an analytics call.

Comment: is there a way to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just add 'useADP:false' to your load options, like this...

```
    var options = {
    env: "Local",
    useADP: false,
}
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer( options, function() {
    viewer.start(myURN, options, onSuccess);            
});
```

etc

Reference:
https://github.com/wallabyway/markupExt/blob/6c55e73226a70a61f33bc7f8f021b44a979c32e2/docs/app.js#L14

This will turn off analytics and remove the error you are seeing. Hope that helps!

UPDATED